# Adding a recurse + silentlycontinue to trashbin delete

Tags: powershell, recursion

I've encountered a problem with my script, whenever I do a trashbin deletion and the map location has a folder within a folder that has an file that has to be deleted, it will not work.

The problem is that I need to add a *recurse* and *-erroraction silently continue*. But I dont know how I can do that since the methods for moving files to trash bin are quite hard in my opinion.

Could you guys help me out?

My code:

```
## Top of the script
   param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [ValidateRange(0,99999)]
   [int]$minutes,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
   [string]$maplocation,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [ValidateSet("Direct","TrashBin")]
   [string]$consequence
  )

  ## Variables
$maxAge = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$minutes)
$files  = Get-ChildItem $maplocation -Recurse
$time = get-date
$fortrashbin =  $maplocation + '\' + $file 

##
foreach ($file in $files)
{
     if ($file.lastwritetime -lt  $maxage) 
     {
        switch ($consequence) 
        {
            "direct" 
            {
                write-verbose "File Found $file" -verbose
                remove-item $file.fullname -recurse -erroraction silentlycontinue
                write-verbose "Deleting $file" -verbose
             }
            "trashbin" {
                write-verbose "File Found $file" -verbose
                write-verbose "moving $file to trashbin" -verbose
                Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
                [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::DeleteFile($fortrashbin,'OnlyErrorDialogs','SendToRecycleBin') 
            }
         }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to iterate over each file if you delete a folder. Instead, you can use the `DeleteDirectory` method:

```
if (Test-Path -Path $maplocation -PathType Container)
{
    # delete directory
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::DeleteDirectory(
        $maplocation,'OnlyErrorDialogs','SendToRecycleBin')
}
else
{
    # delete folder
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::DeleteFile(
        $maplocation,'OnlyErrorDialogs','SendToRecycleBin')
}
```

Please also consider to replace your `$consequence` parameter with a `[switch]` like:

```
param
(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [ValidateRange(0,99999)]
   [int]$minutes,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
   [string]$maplocation,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
   [switch]$Direct
)
```

Now you can invoke your script without any parameters to delete the location to trashbin or with the `-Direct` switch to permanently remove it.